# enlarging image on mouse hover without pushing other images using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I am trying create the image enlargement effect when you hover your mouse over an image thumbnail like the one that Google Images is using. However, I am encountering a problem where the enlarged image keeps pushing the other image to another location depending on the enlarged image's position.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<style>
img{float:left;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#I1").mouseover(function(){

    $("#I1").animate({height:300,width:300},"fast");
   });
 $("#I1").mouseout(function(){
    $("#I1").animate({height:96,width:128},"fast");
   });
});
</script> 

 <img id="I1" src="http://www.dpstudiolab.com/weblog/wp-content/uploads/2007/11/display-pop-up-2.thumbnail.jpg" >
<img id="I2" src="http://www.dpstudiolab.com/weblog/wp-content/uploads/2007/11/display-pop-up-2.thumbnail.jpg" >
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried giving it a higher z-index than the rest and an absolute position? You definitely need to give it an absolute position - this is how you remove it from the DOM stack and make it float there independently without making other elements depend on it.

Or, you can play around with clones like I did here:

.. removed old url ..

Updated with more "images", smoother animation, and removed the bugs from before that used to get an image stuck..

http://jsfiddle.net/Swader/jKTVn/7/

Comment: @user701510 Updated answer with simple solution

Comment: This simple solution stuck after hovering an element 2nd time.

Comment: Hence the word "simple", I didn't really pay much attention to optimizing memory consumption, prevention of creating multiple listeners, etc. I merely posted it for the OP to have some basic idea on how it can be done. But ok, I'll fix the fiddle.

Comment: @Ahsan There you go. Feel free to go wild with the mouse, it won't break now.

Comment: Now it is unstoppable while hover.

Comment: it should be zoomed and must be stopped on mouse over event.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean. I believe the fiddle accomplishes a demonstration of one possible solution, discussing and nitpicking it is not necessary.

Comment: Currently while hovering the color box it zoomed in & out continuously. In my opinion it should be zoomed in and stopped on mouse over event. Mouseout event is perfectly fine.

Comment: See this demo: It should be like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/jKTVn/5/ --- Remove the top `mouseout function`

Comment: Ohh, you're right, I haven't even noticed. Sorry! Thanks, fixed now!

Answer (score 2):

You definitely need to keep it absolutely positioned to remove it from the normal flow. Unfortunately, this also means you need to track the position. I might recommend duplicating an absolutely positioned div directly on top, give it a higher z-index, then animating the expansion of that div. On mouseout, shink it and then remove the element.

```
<style>
.over {
  /* We use this for all of the generated hover-overs */
  position:absolute;
  z-index:2;
}
img {
  float:left;
  position:relative; /* z-index doesn't work unless position is set */
  z-index:1;
}
</style>

<div id="images">
  <img id="img1" src="foo.jpg">
  <img id="img2" src="bar.jpg">
  <img id="img3" src="baz.jpg">
</div>

<script>
  // First catch the mouse enter, grab position, make new element, append it, then animate
  $("img").mouseenter(function() {
    var top = $(this).position().top;
    var left = $(this).position().left;
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    $('<div class="over" style="top:'+top+' left:'+left+'" src="'+src+'"></div>')
     .appendTo($("#images"))
     .animate({height:300,width:300},"fast");
  });

  // Note the mouseleave on the hovered element instead of the img
  $(".over").mouseleave(function() {
    var self = this;
    $(this).animate({height:96,width:128},"fast",function() {
      self.remove();
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: hmm, I copied this code and included the jquery file on the top, but nothing happens when I hovered over the images.

Answer (score 1):

The effetcs that you get on Google Images is on hover lightbox. You can try                  [Suckerfish-Hoverlightbox](http://mondaybynoon.com/2006/03/27/suckerfish-hoverlightbox/) (see the [demo](http://www.mondaybynoon.com/examples/suckerfish_hoverlightbox/horizontal.html)) for this effect. Shifting the size of one image will result in change in position of other images.

Answer (score 1):

See the working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/Gsh6B/3/

You have to take these images in separate DIVs with `div { display:inline }` style applied. You have to set z-index property for the both DIVs and the `position:relative` & `position:absolute` as I did in my demo. Most important is `left:130px` on the 2nd img div that holds the img at the same position.

See Another working demo of the solution given by `Swader` with little modifications:

http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/jKTVn/5/