# Text overlay over image on hover. How to stop other divs from moving

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do i create a text overlay for my image on hover.

Also how do i stop all my other divs from moving when i mouse over my image. 
Like everything on my page shifts slightly. I want nothing else on my page to move, just have the overlay appear on hover. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.
 
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Renay/73h22eqz/) makes more sense. (Open JS box to max so you can see what i'm talking about) 
   
 HTML:

```
<div class='wrapper'>       
    <div id = 'portfolioContainer'> 
        <ul id='portfolioGallery'> 
            <li> 
                <a href="" target="_blank">
                    <img src= "" class='gallImage'>
                    <div class='gallText'> HTML CSS Javascript </div> 
                </a>
            </li>   
            <li> 
                <a href="" target="_blank">
                    <img src= "" class='gallImage'>
                    <div class='gallText'> HTML CSS(Sass) Javascript </div> 
                </a>
            </li>   
            <li> 
                <a href="" target="_blank">
                    <img src= "" class='gallImage' >
                    <div class='gallText'> HTML CSS Javascript </div>
                </a>
            </li>   
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.gallText').hide();

$('.gallImage').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css('opacity','.2');
    $(this).next('div.gallText').show();
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).css('opacity','1');
    $(this).next('div.gallText').hide(); 
});
```

CSS:

```
#portfolioGallery {
    list-style:none;
    text-align: center;
}

#portfolioGallery li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 20px 20px;
}

#portfolioGallery img {
     border:3px solid #021a40;
     width: 350px;
     height: 200px;
    background:#D4CFC7;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to use `visibility: hidden`/`visibility: visible` instead of `display: none;` and `display: block`. `Visibility:hidden` means that unlike display:none, the element is not visible, but space is allocated for it on the page. so for example:

```js
$('.gallText').css("visibility", "hidden");

$('.gallImage').mouseover(function() {
  $(this).css('opacity', '.2');
  $(this).next('div.gallText').css("visibility", "visible");
}).mouseout(function() {
  $(this).css('opacity', '1');
  $(this).next('div.gallText').css("visibility", "hidden");
});
```

```css
#portfolioGallery {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
#portfolioGallery li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
}
#portfolioGallery img {
  border: 3px solid #021a40;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #D4CFC7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>

  <div id='portfolioContainer'>
    <ul id='portfolioGallery'>
      <li>
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <img src="" class='gallImage'>
          <div class='gallText'>HTML CSS Javascript</div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <img src="" class='gallImage'>
          <div class='gallText'>HTML CSS(Sass) Javascript</div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <img src="" class='gallImage'>
          <div class='gallText'>HTML CSS Javascript</div>
        </a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! Explanation was great too. Learned something new from that :) Just a quick question, would you know something similar for when i am enlarging an image on hover, How would i stop everything else from moving??

Comment: Is different situation. You can take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782942/resizing-an-image-and-keep-the-neighbours-where-they-are) for example and also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675329/enlarging-image-on-mouse-hover-without-pushing-other-images-using-jquery)

Comment: I see you've upvoted Alex's answer, but you should accept it as well if it has given you what you need.  For your subsidiary question in your last comment, give the containing div a width & height, that should keep the space needed for the enlarged image. And an alternative way to solve your original problem, which would be useful if there is more popup content than you want to reserve onscreen space for. Position the popup div.gallText absolutely in the CSS (and leave it as display:none), and give the images a relative position so the popup is positioned relative to the preceeding image.